# LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ... could not initialize proxy - no session

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm facing this issue at my job and I don't know how could I achieve this.

I have these classes (which are not real, but are a very simplistic example of the problem, the real ones are very complex)

A Person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors, getters, and setters

}
```

This class have a lazily fetched list of objects, that have:

```
@Entity
public class Object {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private double weight;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

And then I have a DTO to get only the name and the age:

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

Both classes are in the database, the problem is that in the real case, the class object is huge, so it shouldn't be fetched in any case if it is not necessary.

Now the problem appears when I try to do a several checks on that data:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public List<PersonDTO> methodA() {
        List<PersonDTO> personDTOList = methodB();
        methodC(personDTOList);
        return personDTOList;
    }

    @Transactional
    private List<PersonDTO> methodB() {
        List<PersonDTO> personDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Person> personList = personRepository.findAll();

        for (Person person : personList) {
            int objectSize = methodD(person);
            if (objectSize < 50) {
                PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();
                personDTO.setName(person.getName());
                personDTO.setAge(person.getAge());
                personDTOList.add(personDTO);
            }
        }

        return personDTOList;
    }

    private int methodD(Person person) {
        return person.getObjects().size();
    }

    private void methodC(List<PersonDTO> personDTOList) {
        for (PersonDTO personDTO : personDTOList) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + personDTO.getName() + ", Age: " + personDTO.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my main method A is not transactional, because I need to extract a DTO from the data without getting the list of objects, so it can be used later to make changes in database from another table based on the data that is inside the Person ( this is what happens in the real code)

The problem is that when I try to execute the following line of code:

> person.getObjects().size();

It throws me this error:

*Processing of HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call resulted in fatal exception:
name.of.the.class: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
Person.Objects, could not initialize proxy - no Session*

What could be happening?

However, if I use the transactional in the methodA, **everything works**, but I really need to put it in the second method, as I need to do those changes at that moment.

I've tried changing the visibility of all methods and no luck.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

How you can fix it:

**Create a custom object**

```
   public class PersonWithCountObjects {

  private String name;

  private int age;

  private int objectsCount;

  public PersonWithCountObjects(String name, int age, int objectsCount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.objectsCount = objectsCount;
  }
  
  //getter && setter and others methods

  
}
```

**In your PersonRepository  create a DTO projection**

A DTO projection allows you to fetch fewer columns and you won’t risk any LazyInitializationException.

```
  @Query("SELECT new your.packages.path.to.PersonWithCountObjects " +
      " (person.name, person.age, count(person.objects)) " +
      " FROM Person person ")
   List<PersonWithCountObjects> getPersonsWithObjectsCount();
```

And after it in your `methodB()` you will replace

```
List<Person> personList = personRepository.findAll();
```

with

```
List<PersonWithCountObjects> personList = personRepository.getPersonsWithObjectsCount();
```

and make it `public` because you have `@Transactional` annotation on it

you dont need to have this line of code(`int objectSize = methodD(person)`) and also `methodD` you by default will have objects count for every person in field `objectsCount` from `PersonWithCountObjects`

And your for loop will look so:

```
for (PersonWithCountObjects person : personList) {
            if (person.getObjectsCount() < 50) {
                PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();
                personDTO.setName(person.getName());
                personDTO.setAge(person.getAge());
                personDTOList.add(personDTO);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional only with public method. You can update your code to something like:

```
@Transactional
public List<PersonDTO> methodB() {
...
}
```

The reason why it works when you put @Transactional in your methodA is because methodA has public access modifier. And it bypasses the transaction to methodB inside it.